# How can I find a specific element's index when there're multiple of the same values in Python?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make my own sorting program, it works properly when the values in listToSort are all different but if 2 or more of the numbers are the same it doesn't work anymore. I think the problem is that when I search for the index of a value in listToSort it gives me the first value in the list and not the one I intended. Is there any way this could be solved?

Here's an example of numbers that doesn't work

```
listToSort = [4, 3, 4, 3]

for x in range(len(listToSort)):
    lowestNumber = listToSort[x]
    for i in range(x, len(listToSort)):
        if lowestNumber > listToSort[i]:
            lowestNumber = listToSort[i]
    lowestNumberIndex = listToSort.index(lowestNumber)
    listToSort[x], listToSort[lowestNumberIndex] = listToSort[lowestNumberIndex], listToSort[x]

print("Sorted", listToSort)
```

Comment: Read the documentation of list.index _ you can supply a "where to start looking" parameter. So you find the 1st on on pos 2 and then use index("..", 3) to search behind position 2 afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the index starting from the current position, you can give the position to start from directly to `index`:

```
listToSort.index(lowestNumber, x)
```

This will give you the index starting from the currently unsorted values, instead of the first occurence in the list. After changing that, the output will be correct:

```
Sorted [3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `index` function, as you can save the index during your search of the lowest element:

```
listToSort = [4, 3, 4, 3]

for x in range(len(listToSort)):
    lowestNumber = listToSort[x]
    lowestNumberIndex = x
    for i in range(x, len(listToSort)):
        if lowestNumber > listToSort[i]:
            lowestNumber = listToSort[i]
            lowestNumberIndex = i
    listToSort[x], listToSort[lowestNumberIndex] = listToSort[lowestNumberIndex], listToSort[x]

print("Sorted", listToSort)
```